# D3.js: Clustered Force layout with text and tool tips

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am quite new to D3.js and I have been working on this clustered force layout: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887

I have been trying to add text to the center of the circles and tool tips on mouse over. However, I have failed.

Here is my effort:

```
//For text
node = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.r/m); })
    .attr("class", "circles")
    .call(force.drag);

word = node.append("text")
          .data(nodes)
          .text(function(d) { console.log(d);return d.cluster.substring(0, d.r/ 3); }); 


//For tool tip

node.on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
        tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      
        tooltip.html(d.word)  
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
    })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        tooltip.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);   
    });
```

I would be really grateful if someone helped me figure this out!

Thanks! :)

EDIT: The tool tip variable:

```
   var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")   
        .attr("class", "tooltip")               
        .style("opacity", 0);
```

Comment: You can't append text to circles. Please read the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640027/add-text-label-to-d3-node-in-force-layout/37640083#37640083

Comment: Thank you! That question helped. But I am still not able to figure out the tool tips...

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have right now for the tooltips?

Comment: I have already shared it with the comment `for tool tip`.

Comment: I'm asking about the `tooltip` variable.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Will update the question.

Comment: It's working to me, no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for the tooltips seems to be alright. Maybe the problem is in your CSS. Here is what I did, you can style it better:

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: left;
    background: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is the fiddle, you can see that the tooltips are working: https://jsfiddle.net/L8ecvwoz/2/