# How to add node labels to Bounded Force Layout (D3 v4)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, graph-visualization

Latest code attempt:

```
 var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius - .75)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.group)).darker(); })
      .call(force.drag);

  var label = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d){return d.id; }); 
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "red");
 })

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

  function tick() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    label.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
          .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y });
```

---

Hi Everyone,

I am a newbie to D3 and have spent almost two days on this problem so far to no avail!

I am trying to add node labels to a version of https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492

I've copy/pasted snippets of code from every forum response I can find and it either breaks my diagram (empty screen on execution) or has no effect (lots of pretty colored circles but no labels).  I have been able to add labels to another force diagram successfully but that one was not bounded, and bounding is a key feature I'd like to have.  At this stage I have not made any changes to the graph.json file Bostock put up.  I am simply trying to get it to display the node text labels.

Can someone please tell me what code I need to write to get labels to show, and where and how to to insert it?  I'm determined to not give up on this one!

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
circle {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
line {
  stroke: #999;
}
text {
    font: 12px "open sans";
    fill: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = 6;

var fill = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.range(["#a02a65","#2aa02a","#2aa0a0","#a0652a","#a02a2a","#2a2aa0","#65a02a","#a0a02a"])

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .velocityDecay(0.1)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(.05))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(.05))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-240))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(50).strength(1));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("https://[URL HERE]/graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

var link = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line");
  var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius - .75)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.group)).darker(); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
    
    var labels = node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      })
      .attr('x', 6)
      .attr('y', 3);
  
  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", tick);
  simulation.force('link')
      .links(graph.links);
  function tick() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  }
});
function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}
function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The variable node appears to be selection of circle elements with titles but titles are not generally rendered (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title). You might want to either repeat the circle data-join but for text elements or create group elements for each node and then append both a circle and a label.

Comment: Hey John! thanks so much for responding.  That all sounds great but I have no idea how to implement what you're suggesting code-wise.  Any chance you could point me in the right direction with code snippet/s?  thanks again!!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37640083/7106086

Comment: Thank you! So I've studied the links and had another attempt but am simply just not getting it - I'm studying javascript and D3 but the extent of my (lack of) experience is showing.  Any chance I can get some code help?   Here's my latest:

Comment: [at top of original question] -- and thanks again (honestly!)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the [example from Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492) to include labels for each node by doing the following:

1. The label for each node is in `graph.nodes` so first we create a
   selection `labels` and perform a typical d3 data-join to add text
   elements and set the label-text.
2. The positioning of the labels occurs in the `tick()` function. On
   each step of the animation, we set the `x` and `y` attribute of the
   text element according to the x and y value of the `graph.node`
   element.

Please note that this example uses d3 v3 so there will be some changes to the syntax - primarily the names used for scale etc. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

I have not attempted to position the text to avoid overlapping. This is reasonably involved and discussed elsewhere like [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425268/d3js-automatic-labels-placement-to-avoid-overlaps-force-repulsion).

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = 6;
    
var fill = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.05)
    .charge(-240)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width, height]);
    
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1129492/raw/9513c3fe193673a09e161d49d00a587fd806bdf5/graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  var link = svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line");
    
  var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius - .75)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.group); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.group)).darker(); })
      .call(force.drag);
  
  var labels = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('text')
      .text(function (d){return d.name});
      
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();
      
  function tick() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
        
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    
    labels.attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});
```

```css
circle {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
line {
  stroke: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey John.  Thank you!!!  I'm going to get stick into this tomorrow.  I'll let you know how I do.  Amy.